# HTML 5 canvas toDataURL changed raw data

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, base64, todataurl

I use canvas to draw an image only, but toDataURL() value is different with raw data even if canvas did not change.
the code as blow:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>For test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        window.onload = function() {
            var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
            var img = document.getElementById("scream");
            img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

            console.log(c.toDataURL().length);
            console.log("data:img/jpg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADUAAAAzCAIAAAC43dc6AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAABPSURBVGhD7dOhAQAgDMAw/n96GCyqZiK5oKZndtPX6Gv0NfoafY2+Rl+jr9HXrO8D/t4nW+lr9DX6Gn2NvkZfo6/R1+hr9DX6Gn3N7r6ZCxmTdxPs4RLCAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC".length);

        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Image to use:</p>
<img id="scream" src="data:img/jpg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADUAAAAzCAIAAAC43dc6AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAABPSURBVGhD7dOhAQAgDMAw/n96GCyqZiK5oKZndtPX6Gv0NfoafY2+Rl+jr9HXrO8D/t4nW+lr9DX6Gn2NvkZfo6/R1+hr9DX6Gn3N7r6ZCxmTdxPs4RLCAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" /><p>
<p>Canvas:</p>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="53" height="51"></canvas>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple: you are re-applying the jpeg compression, which is a lossy process. Unless your original image came from a  from the same computer, it's a virtually impossibility that they would match exactly. Even if you used the exact same algo, you have to match the quality factor to get a re-encode match. I don't even see the quality being specified in the code (as an [argument to `toDataURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL)).

Even if you used all the same settings, there's a slight bit of voodoo in these encoders, and a device resolution change, zooming, font updates, or a bogged down CPU can all (potentially) affect the output, due to the dynamic nature of canvas layout. Apps like photoshop are much more repeatable than browsers.